# How to use a value from a 2-D list as an argument in a function

Tags: python, function, class, tkinter

I am trying to use a value from a 2-d list to serve as an argument for a function that is used for most of the buttons in the GUI. When I call the `add_to_display` function and click on one of the buttons the display entry shows `".!frame.!button16"` instead of one of the string values from the button list.

```
from tkinter import * 

class Functions():        
    def replace_text(self, text):
        self.display.delete(0, END)
        self.display.insert(0, text)

    def add_to_display(self, text, *args):
        self.user_input = self.display.get()
        self.text_length = len(self.user_input)

        if self.user_input == "0":
           self.replace_text(text)
        else: 
           self.display.insert(self.text_length, text)


class Calculator(Functions):
   def __init__(self, root):
      frame = ttk.Frame(root)
      frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0)        

      self.display = Entry(frame, font=("Helvetica", 14), justify = "right")
      self.display.insert(0, "0")
      self.display.grid(column = 0, row = 0, columnspan = 4, sticky = "NSWE", padx = 10, pady = 10)

      self.button_list = [["7", "8", "9", "+"],
                        ["4", "5", "6", "-"],
                        ["1", "2", "3", "x"],
                        ["C", "0", ".", "/"]]

      for row_ in range(len(self.button_list)):
          for column_ in range(len(self.button_list[row_])):
              self.button_list[row_][column_] = Button(frame, font= ("Helvetica", 12), text = self.button_list[row_][column_],
                                                     command = lambda: self.add_to_display(self.button_list[row_][column_]))
              self.button_list[row_][column_].grid(row = row_ + 1 , column = column_, sticky = "NSWE")


#Main Program       
root = Tk() 
root.title("Calculator Trial 2")
App = Calculator(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem lies in the call

```
self.button_list[row_][column_] = Button(frame, font= ("Helvetica", 12), text = self.button_list[row_][column_], command = lambda: self.add_to_display(self.button_list[row_][column_]))
```

There are two problems in this line:

1. The lambda function is executed after overwriting the variable `self.button_list [row _] [column_]` and therefore the variable is no longer the original string you wanted
2. Also, this order of execution causes the row_ and column_ variables to both be 3 (so saving the buttons in another list would not solve your problem)

My suggested solution would be the use of the partial function from the module functools. It worked for me.

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial

class Functions():        
    def replace_text(self, text):
        self.display.delete(0, END)
        self.display.insert(0, text)

    def add_to_display(self, text, *args):
        self.user_input = self.display.get()
        self.text_length = len(self.user_input)

        if self.user_input == "0":
           self.replace_text(text)
        else: 
           self.display.insert(self.text_length, text)


class Calculator(Functions):
    def __init__(self, root):
        frame = Frame(root)
        frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0)        

        self.display = Entry(frame, font=("Helvetica", 14), justify = "right")
        self.display.insert(0, "0")
        self.display.grid(column = 0, row = 0, columnspan = 4, sticky = "NSWE", padx = 10, pady = 10)

        self.button_list = [["7", "8", "9", "+"],
                        ["4", "5", "6", "-"],
                        ["1", "2", "3", "x"],
                        ["C", "0", ".", "/"]]

        for row_ in range(len(self.button_list)):
            for column_ in range(len(self.button_list[row_])):
                self.button_list[row_][column_] = Button(frame, font= ("Helvetica", 12), text = self.button_list[row_][column_],
                                                     command = partial(self.add_to_display, self.button_list[row_][column_]))
                self.button_list[row_][column_].grid(row = row_ + 1 , column = column_, sticky = "NSWE")


#Main Program       
root = Tk() 
root.title("Calculator Trial 2")
App = Calculator(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Some things I should add:

1. Note that the ttk.Frame call should trigger an error.
2. Even if the unusual / false indentation does not cause an error in this case, it is recommended to use a uniform indentation in each script

Good Luck!